# Xamarin forms - Your app supports Multitasking on iPad, so you must include the UILaunchStoryboardName key in your bundle

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, publish

When publishing Xamarin.Forms iOS app I get this error

ERROR ITMS-90475: "Invalid Bundle. Your app supports Multitasking on iPad, so you must include the UILaunchStoryboardName key in your bundle. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW40)."

We do not use storyboards in Xamarin.Forms iOS app. How to fix this?

Comment: You can still add a launch storyboard. The launch storyboard is used by iOS to show content before your code starts running.

Comment: Got it, however found an approach without adding one.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/301331/#Comment_301331

Add these lines to info.plist
`<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key> <string>LaunchScreen</string>`